# Parameterize then Replay trc files SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-profiler

I've recorded using the SQLServer Profiler a trace file to be replayed (trc file).
I'm following the instructions from this [article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2005/stress-test-part3/) to stress my server.

I have to manipulate this file to parameterize and randomize part of it.

What is the best way to do that ? I was unable to find an API to parse my trace file and modify it.... The solution I'm considering is to export the trace as a T-Sql file and modify the script.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go furthermore with your suggestion (and actually the article suggested it too).
I'd create a Stored Procedure that will allow to parameterize the trace.
And then, a code like the LoadConnection from your article

```
public class LoadConnection
{
              public void startConnection()
              {
                          Try
                          {
                                      SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection();
                                      conn.ConnectionString = “Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog =<yourDatabase>;Data Source=<yourServer>;Connect Timeout=600;Pooling=false;Application Name=’<yourApplicationName>’”;
                                      conn.Open();
                                      SqlCommand comm=new SqlCommand();
                                      comm.Connection=conn;
                                      comm.CommandTimeout = 600;
                                      comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                      comm.CommandText = “<yourStoredProcedure>”;

                                      SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("<your parameter>", RandomParam1());
                                      comm.Parameters.Add(param1);


                                      comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                      conn.Close();
                          }
                          catch(Exception ex)
                          {
                                      MessageBox.Show(“Error”,ex.Message);
                          }
              }
};
```

`
With RandomParam1() being a method that you would have created to randomize this type/kind of parameter.

Hope that helped.